# How to populate dynamic PHP variable in text field of Contact Form 7 - WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to populate dynamic PHP variable in text field of Contact Form 7.

The dynamic PHP variable is actually a dynamic URL coming through another plugin. For example, the PHP variable is: $uniquelink

So far I have done the following:

```
[text unique_url <?php echo $uniquelink; ?>]
```

and also tried:

```
[text unique_url "<?php echo $uniquelink; ?>"]
```

But this is not working. Also, there is no shortcode to display that dynamic PHP variable. Hence cannot use Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension plugin.

Please advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "But this is not working", you haven't told us _what isn't working_. What is your output? What is your expected output? **_what is your question_**?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I am getting blank output on web page. Expected output, for example is: http://example.com/unique?link=ref12345